# AWS - Status check fails when loading AMI created from snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a running micro instance using an 8GB EBS that I've customized.

To my understand there are two ways I can create an AMI from this.

1) EC2 console -> INSTANCES - Instances -> Right Click instance -> Create Image (EBS AMI)

2) EC2 console -> ELASTIC BLOCK STORE - Volumes -> Right Click Volume -> Create Snapshot, then go to snapshots and Right "Create Image From Snapshot"

When I right click and Select "Launch Instance" from my list of private AMIs, I'm able to successfully launch an instance from the AMI generated from the first method.  However whenever I try to launch an instance from the AMI generated by the 2nd method, the Status Checks show either 1/2 checks passed or 0/2 checks passed.

Why am I unable to launch an instance from an AMI generated from the snapshot?

Comment: At a guess (check your console log, you might get more info) - either your AKI (kernel) or fstab (mounted volumes) differ. Check which AKI each image is launch with and see if they match. If it is your fstab trying to mount a non-existent volume, it should show up in your console log.

Comment: @cyberx86 Thanks so much, I was using the default kernel to make the image.  Is the console log in the aws console or is it cli?  I couldn't find a console log in the aws console.

Comment: You can usually view the console log from the AWS Console. In the EC2 tab, right click an instance, and select 'Get System Log' - of course, the instance has to have at least started booting (it is basically an output of dmesg on Linux instances).

Comment: Are you using a RedHat or CentOS AMI? There are (were) some issues with the way the network connection was managed that prevented copying EBS-based images.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an image from a snapshot, make sure you use the same architecture you used for the original instance/AMI. The default value in this wizard is i386, but in many cases you may want x86_64, which is the standard Amazon EC2 Linux architecture. This, together with selecting the exact AKI kernel - worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your original instance supported para-virtualization or HVM.

This value can be found on your original EC2 instance's description section as 'Virtualization' and also on the AMI's description section as 'Virtualization type'.

When making AMI using the EBS instead of the EC2 instance, this value could be set incorrectly (the values must match so future instances are made using the right form of virtualization).